# Firebase data read before operation android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app that reads total number of posts. After that a user writes another post then the total number of post is updated. Also stores post with  "postno"+totalPost as the key.

But whenever the operation is performed ,it throws a null-pointer exception on postNo.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer postNo=dataSnapshot.child("posts").getValue(Integer.class);
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            database.getReference("posts").setValue(postNo+1);
            DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("users/postno" + postNo);
            reference.setValue(new Post());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Listener Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.team.speedcoders.friendsforever.MyActivity$2$1.onDataChange(MyActivity.java:129)
                        //129no line contains "database.getReference("posts").setValue(postNo+1);"

Comment: It seems database.getReference("posts") is returning null could you debug it please?

Comment: I have done that too